# How to decode a json response from API

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am calling data from an API like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
//adding fields to the curl object to enter the site
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

//executing the curl call and getting data back
$jsonStr = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl); // close the connection

print_r($jsonStr);
```

it is working fine but the thing is that I cannot decode the json response. I am getting something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Books","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"200.0000"}],"tax":[]},{"id":2,"name":"pencil","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"5000.0000"}],"tax":[]}]
```

I tried to decode that and calling a value like "echo $code[0]['name'];" and I couldn´t, it shows the same json array, then I tried to save the json array into a variable like:

```
$json = '[{"id":1,"name":"Books","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"200.0000"}],"tax":[]},{"id":2,"name":"pencil","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"5000.0000"}],"tax":[]}]';
```

and tried to decode it and it works, I think the problems is with single quotations.I am not sure but it is what I am assuming base on the results I am getting. I am new at curl, json and php so if someone can help me.

By the way, I am trying to decode like this:

```
$code = json_decode($jsonStr ,true);
echo $code[0]['id'];
```

but it is not working, it returns the same complete json array and not the value I am trying to get

when I am trying to echoing $jsonStr I get:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Books","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"200.0000"}],"tax":[]},{"id":2,"name":"pencil","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"5000.0000"}],"tax":[]}]
```

Comment: *something like this*... What do you **actually** get?

Comment: @BenM the json array bellow,

Comment: And how are you trying to decode it?

Comment: @BenM I edited my question and added the way I am trying to decode the json array

Comment: @Vec what do you get if you echo `$jsonStr`?

Comment: @BenM I need to get a value from json array. But when I decode jsonStr and try to get $json[0]['id'], it returns the same complete json array and not the value I am want to

Comment: @Vec, I know. But my question was what you see by just echoing out `$jsonStr`, without any decoding.

Comment: @BenM I edited my question again and added the echo $jsonStr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode() method

Please refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is not working for you. When the json string is in the code it does work.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"id":1,"name":"Books","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"200.0000"}],"tax":[]},{"id":2,"name":"pencil","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"5000.0000"}],"tax":[]}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$id = $arr[0]['id'];
$name = $arr[0]['name'];
print("$id $name\n");
```

Ouput:

```
1 Books
```

Btw my version

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2017 12:20:45)
```

Comment: yeah like that works but I when I am trying to decode $jsonStr it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()`. If you want to view the php object so you can better understand how to use it, try

```
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r(json_decode($jsonStr, true));
echo '</pre>';
```