# How can I echo a json value from a json array called from API

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to know how can I get any value from the JSON array I am getting from an API.

I am calling data like this:

```
//initializing curl object
$curl = curl_init();
//adding fields to the curl object to enter the site
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');

//executing the curl call and getting data back
$json = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl); // close the connection
```

I am getting this json array printed on my html:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Books","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"200.0000"}],"tax":[]},{"id":2,"name":"pencil","description":null,"reference":null,"status":"active","category":{"id":"5048","name":"Ventas"},"price":[{"idPriceList":"1","name":"General","type":"amount","price":"5000.0000"}],"tax":[]}]
```

what I want is to get only one or two values from that json array, I mean I tried this:

```
$code = json_decode($json, true);
echo $code[0]['id'];
```

but it seems like it doesn´t work because I am still getting the same JSON array printed in my HTML and not the value I want to be displayed. I need to hide all the other values and just let displayed the one I want.

Comment: By not posting the same question three times in less than 24 hours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264294/get-json-values-from-array-in-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278441/how-to-decode-a-json-response-from-api

Comment: You probably just accidentally echo the response you get from curl somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell curl to return the value, not print it:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```